Can I just remove NC pads to route signals underneath?
I have a USB-C footprint that looks like this:

In this application, I have A5, A6, A7 all disconnected. Can I remove the pads for A6, A7, A5 to gain additional space to route signals on the front layer?

You already got an answer, so just a comment that your pinout is likely very wrong. Is that even a plug or receptacle? Why would you even have A5 disconnected, any good reason? Cables also don't swap B5/A8 or B8/B5 or A5/A8 as none of them are pairs.

@Justme I'm honestly not sure. It's a clone of a proprietary USB cable and the original designer only implemented one side of the connector (so it's unidirectional). Everything about this original cable is wrong (TX->TX, RX->RX, the A5/A8 pairs are all jumbled, D+ goes to D-, etc.). I'm guessing the original manufacturer did this to prevent people from using off-the-shelf cables.

The D+ and D- are still wrong. And if it's proprietary then it can't be USB. And if that is a plug then pins B6 and B7 should not even be present. It may be that you can't find a plug with B6 and B7.

No. The pins will still of course be there and the soldermask will probably introduce coplanarity issues that will complicate soldering. In any case, soldermask cannot be counted on as insulation.

Yes. We had a connector with four rows of pins, and wanted to remove some pads on the outer rows to route to the inner rows. We posed this same question to one of our assembly houses a few weeks ago, and they said that this is something that many customers request, and something they can usually accommodate, depending on the component. They asked that we make a note of it in the assembly drawing and they would adjust the thickness of the solder stencil and modify the paste layer accordingly.
That being said, I didn't see it mentioned in the IPC-610 standard, so this is probably not a sanctioned practice. For a prototype PCB this is probably fine, but not for something that you would give to a client.
